# ssh connection freeze after password phase

Tags: networking, ssh, linux-networking

I'm trying to connect to a server (Oracle Linux 6.3) and after I insert the password the session just freeze.
I checked the audit log and I've authenticated successfully, after I restarted the networking service everything is fine until the next time it happens.
Does anyone has idea?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Please provide the specific `ssh` command that you're running.

Comment: is this a connection via VPN? if so check MTU settings of the VPN tunnel.

Comment: I use regular ssh `ssh user@someserver` in the LAN network so no vpn involved.

Answer (score 0):

I see this being related to DNS sometimes. Try giving it this flag on your ssh command "-vvv"

This will give verbose output.

Comment: I tried that but the last line i got is: `debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768`

Comment: Try from another location, I have seen this error caused by the ISP before.

Comment: Its in my LAN network

Comment: Do you have a way to debug in the server side? `-vv` is good for spotting client errors, but sometimes is the server the one failing. If you reached the `open confirm` the server accepted the connection and the authentication, the only steps missing is requesting PTY and requesting shell. If you're able to do so set  `LogLevel DEBUG` in the `sshd` config and watch the logs there.